# Why wont my script work for alerting upon image finding?

Tags: image, alert, greasemonkey

Alright basically i have the code at the bottom and it works perfectly if i give the full image url but im trying to get it to work if i only give part of it and use a * for the other part.

```
var theList = ['*this.png','site.com/folder/*'];

for(i=0; i<theImages.length; i++) {
   for(j=0; j<theList.length; j++) {
      if(theImages[i].src==theList[j]) alert(theList[j]+' found on this page');
   }
}
```

Please and thanks

Comment: It's not working because you used `==` instead of something that would take the wildcard * into account.

Comment: Alright ill try this and get back to you

Comment: Wot thank you so much this website is the best
But you should post as an answer if you want me to mark as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I... didn't really think my comment would help, but since it seems it did, I guess I'll post it as an answer:

It's not working because you used == instead of something that would take the wildcard * into account.